# Swift Siesta Get and post

Tags: swift3, siesta-swift

I am new to Siesta. How can I get the entire array and pass into my model? Besides, how can I post with params? In their documentation I couldn't find any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to siesta as well. I was able to find documentation about requests here http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/requests/

Basically you'll setup your resource and then call:

```
resource.request(.post, json: ["foo": [1,2,3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too complex so I will try to explain you in a simple way.

1. Siesta provides a great way to map your models by using Custom Transformers. One simple way to do this is to implement the Decodable protocol provided by Swift 4+:

Lets say we want to decode this JSON response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oswaldo",
    "email": "omaestra@gmail.com"
}
```

Into our great `User` class which implements the Decodable protocol:

```
class User: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var email: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, email
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
    }
}
```

Awesome! Now we can decode the JSON response from our server into our awesome `User` class.

Next, inside our `Siesta.Service` class we can configure our custom transformers for specific resources:

```
class API: Siesta.Service {
    init() { 
        super.init(baseURL: "https://api.example.com")
        // Some initial configuration
    }

    let myAPI = API()

    // –––––– Global configuration ––––––
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

    // –––––– Mapping from specific paths to models ––––––
    // These all use Swift 4’s JSONDecoder, but you can configure arbitrary transforms on arbitrary data types.
    configureTransformer("rest/user/") {
        // Input type inferred because the from: param takes Data.
        // Output type inferred because jsonDecoder.decode() will return User
        try jsonDecoder.decode(User.self, from: $0.content)
    }

    // MARK: - Resources
    var userResource: Siesta.Resource { return resource("rest/user/") }
}
```

Finally, we can implement our resource inside our `ViewController`:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myAPI.userResource
            .addObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        myAPI.userResource.loadIfNeeded()
    }
}

extension UserViewController: ResourceObserver {
    func resourceChanged(_ resource: Resource, event: ResourceEvent) {
        let user: User? = resource.typedContent()
        nameLabel.text = user?.name
        emailLabel.text = user?.email
    }
}
```

Note: Siesta is very flexible and customisable framework, you can find multiple ways to configure your services and resources. This is just one simple way to implement what you are asking for.

---

1. To make a POST request with params you can do something like this inside your `Service` class:

Implement an `update` method that makes the POST request.

```
func update(user: User, newName: String) -> Siesta.Request {
    return usersResource
        .child(user.id)
        .child("update")
        .request(.post, json: ["name": newName])
}
```

Then, in your `ViewController` you can call the method to submit the `POST` request and evaluate its response:

```
myAPI.update(user: user, newName: "NEW NAME")
    .onSuccess({ (_) in
            print("Successfully updated user's name.")
        })
    .onFailure({ (error) in
            print("Error trying to update user's name.")
        })
```